# Titanium: Have scrollview auto play slides

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a typical createScrollableView control.
How do i make the slides play by them selves, not wait for user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `scrollToView` method inside a timer function. Try this below:

```
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({...Your initialization here...});

// Goto the next page every 1.5 seconds.
// Loop around at the end
setInterval(function() {
    var numPages = scrollableView.children.length;
    var page = scrollableView.currentPage;
    page = page + 1 % numPages;
    scrollableView.scrollToView(page);
}, 1500);
```